# Pagination logic shows incorrect page numbers

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to resolve this issue and can't seem to fix it and
am a little unsure what is wrong - I didn't write the code initially.

The code below is meant to show 20 results per page - that works ok.
However there is always an extra page number over and above what there
should be. So if there should be page numbers 1 to 5 - there is page numbers
one to six and the sixth page has no results. It works fine if there is
less than 20 results - just when over multiple pages where the problem appears.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
var js_array = <?php print json_encode($array);?> ;
//alert(1);
//alert(js_array[0]);
for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    //alert(js_array[i]);
    $('#canvas').append(js_array[i]);
}


var end = document.createElement('div');
end.innerHTML = '<b><?php echo $pagewords; ?></b> ';
//alert(js_array.length/15);
var pages = Math.min(Math.round(js_array.length/15), 10);
for (i=1; i<pages; i++)
{   
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    $(span).attr('id', 'span');
    $(span).css('cursor','pointer');
    span.innerHTML = i;
    $(end).append(span);
    $(end).append('  ');

}
$(end).addClass("<?php echo $pageclass; ?>");
$('#main').append(end);

$('span').click(function(){
    //alert($(this).html());
    var page = $(this).html();
    //alert(page);
    $('#canvas').empty();
    if (page==0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            //alert(js_array[i]);
            $('#canvas').append(js_array[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=page*20-20; i<page*20; i++)
        {
            //alert(js_array[i]);
            $('#canvas').append(js_array[i]);
        }
    }


});
```

Can anyone see a problem with the logic of the above.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From this line in your code it appears you are calculating your pagination based on 15 results per page

```
var pages = Math.min(Math.round(js_array.length/15), 10);
```

Comment: That's what I thought - I did try it at 20 but it didn't make a difference. I returned it to the original code when I posted it.

Comment: yes just tried again and cleared cache just in case but if I change it to 15 then I loose a page of results - so if I change it to 15 it goes - as an example - from showing page numbers up to 6 to page numbers up 4

Comment: Try changing 'round' to 'ceil' on the same line. If you have a result of 5.12 pages, then it's currently being rounded down.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gadget but I tried that and it did not make a difference - it was just the same as when round was used.

Comment: Are you able to provide the HTML snippet the JavaScript applies to? I will run a test and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to round up:

```
var pages = Math.ceil(js_array.length/20);
```

this will give you at least 1 page if you have < 20 items.

The Math.min there will force maximum 10 pages. Maybe you want to keep that but for number of pages just use ceil.

Comment: thanks for trying but still get the same results - there should be five pages in an example I am trying but when I change it to the above it shows numbers 1 to 4. My original shows 1 to 6 but both are wrong as there are 100 results which should be five pages.

Comment: @OLM256 remember that the result will be 0-based (0-4) so you need to add 1 to get the page number.